# find remaining amounts with variables

Tags: c, function, numbers

I am taking in a limited amount, and assigning them to an array... done that.

For example... I have only 100 tickets for a raffle. So, I can only assign 100 tickets for how ever many people buy tickets. Some people may buy 19, some might buy 1. But when I get to 100, I don't know how to stop and check, and only give the person the remaining amount of tickets left.

Here is some code.

my function call:

```
int raffle_person, raffle_ticket, person;
                fscanf(ifp, "%d", &raffle_ticket);
                fscanf(ifp, "%d", &raffle_person);


            profit+=  Raffle(raffle_person,raffle_ticket, number_raffle_items,raffle_price, num_raffle_ticket);
            num_raffle_ticket = num_raffle_ticket - raffle_ticket;

            }
```

Basically it scans in the info from a file, then calls the function (ignore profit) and then takes the number of the tickets and subtracts it from the amount the person bought.

Here is the function:

```
float Raffle (int person, int amt_raffle_tickets, int
num_raffle_prize,float price_of_raffle_ticket, int num_raffle_ticket
)
{
    int i; float profit = 0;

    if (num_raffle_ticket <= amt_raffle_tickets){

        if (num_raffle_ticket - amt_raffle_tickets >0){
            int k;
            k = amt_raffle_tickets + num_raffle_ticket;

            printf("RAFFLE TICKETS %d - %d given to PERSON %d\n", raffle_index, k + amt_raffle_tickets -1 , person);
        }

        printf("NO rffle tikes given to %d\n" , person); return 0; } else if
            (num_raffle_ticket < amt_raffle_tickets){

            } printf("RAFFLE TICKETS %d - %d given to PERSON %d\n", raffle_index,
                    raffle_index + amt_raffle_tickets -1 , person);

        for (i=0; i<amt_raffle_tickets; i++){
            myRaffle.raffle_ticket[raffle_index] = person;    profit+= price_of_raffle_ticket;
            raffle_index++;

        }

        return profit;
}
```

First if statement checks to see if the amount the person is buying is already greater...then stops the function... (works)

But I am having problems because I don't know how to assign the remaining amount of tickets to a person. Like if I already assigned 96 tickets, how would I find the difference from 100 and only assign the four to this person?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. I've reformatted your code a bit — but you've got a very unorthodox layout style which you should revise to become more orthodox. To present code on SO, format it offline with no tabs and (recommended) indent level of 4. Copy'n'paste it into the edit box; highlight it, and press the **`{}`** (code) button above the edit box to indent it.

Comment: To answer your question: `if (num_raffle_tickets > amt_raffle_tickets) num_raffle_tickets = amt_raffle_tickets;`.  This sets the number of raffle tickets allocated to the number available if the number requested is larger than the number available.

Comment: For coding styles, see [Indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) or [Code Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_style) at Wikipedia.

Comment: I dont understand... where does that go? I have two if statments... i tried it in both and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your function as originally written laid out in a more orthodox
style:

```
float Raffle(int person, int amt_raffle_tickets, int num_raffle_prize,
             float price_of_raffle_ticket, int num_raffle_ticket)
```

The `amt_raffle_tickets` argument is the requested number of tickets;
the `num_raffle_ticket` argument is the number of tickets available.

```
{
    int i;
    float profit = 0;

    if (num_raffle_ticket <= amt_raffle_tickets)
    {
        if (num_raffle_ticket - amt_raffle_tickets > 0)
        {
            int k;
            k = amt_raffle_tickets + num_raffle_ticket;
            printf("RAFFLE TICKETS %d - %d given to PERSON %d\n",
                   raffle_index, k + amt_raffle_tickets - 1, person);
        }
        printf("NO raffle tickets given to %d\n", person);
        return 0;
```

This `printf()` and `return` looks like it is misplaced, perhaps meant
to go in the empty block of statements in the `else if` clause.
However, the `else if` block will never be entered because the condition
is covered by the `if` condition above, which leaves the question of what
the `printf()` and `return` are supposed to do.

```
    }
    else if (num_raffle_ticket < amt_raffle_tickets)
    { 
    }
    printf("RAFFLE TICKETS %d - %d given to PERSON %d\n", raffle_index,
           raffle_index + amt_raffle_tickets -1, person);

    for (i = 0; i < amt_raffle_tickets; i++)
    {
        myRaffle.raffle_ticket[raffle_index] = person;
        profit+= price_of_raffle_ticket;
        raffle_index++;
    }

    return profit;
}
```

Unfortunately, the variable `raffle_index` is not declared, so we can
presume it is a global variable, and given the way it is printed must be
an `int raffle_index`.  Similarly, your `myRaffle` structure is not
documented either, which again makes it hard to know what's going on.
However, I'd be confident that the structure should hold the value of
`raffle_index`.  The argument `num_raffle_prize` is never used.

I've worked around the unspecified bits and come up with working code.
It reads from standard input and not from a file because I'm lazy.

Example run of fixed code:

```
$ ./raffle
13 3
RAFFLE TICKETS 0 - 12 given to PERSON 3
15 2
RAFFLE TICKETS 13 - 27 given to PERSON 2
17 231
RAFFLE TICKETS 28 - 44 given to PERSON 231
Ticket 0 for person 3
Ticket 1 for person 3
Ticket 2 for person 3
Ticket 3 for person 3
Ticket 4 for person 3
Ticket 5 for person 3
Ticket 6 for person 3
Ticket 7 for person 3
Ticket 8 for person 3
Ticket 9 for person 3
Ticket 10 for person 3
Ticket 11 for person 3
Ticket 12 for person 3
Ticket 13 for person 2
Ticket 14 for person 2
Ticket 15 for person 2
Ticket 16 for person 2
Ticket 17 for person 2
Ticket 18 for person 2
Ticket 19 for person 2
Ticket 20 for person 2
Ticket 21 for person 2
Ticket 22 for person 2
Ticket 23 for person 2
Ticket 24 for person 2
Ticket 25 for person 2
Ticket 26 for person 2
Ticket 27 for person 2
Ticket 28 for person 231
Ticket 29 for person 231
Ticket 30 for person 231
Ticket 31 for person 231
Ticket 32 for person 231
Ticket 33 for person 231
Ticket 34 for person 231
Ticket 35 for person 231
Ticket 36 for person 231
Ticket 37 for person 231
Ticket 38 for person 231
Ticket 39 for person 231
Ticket 40 for person 231
Ticket 41 for person 231
Ticket 42 for person 231
Ticket 43 for person 231
Ticket 44 for person 231
Profit = 90.00
$
```

Working code

Major variable renaming went on.  The program is about raffles, so
there's really no need to repeat `raffle` everywhere.  I didn't
completely expunge it, but I did rename quite a lot of variables.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAX_TICKETS = 100 };
static int raffle_index = 0;
static struct
{
    int raffle_ticket[MAX_TICKETS];
} myRaffle;
static float Raffle(int person, int req_tickets,
                    float ticket_price, int avail_tickets);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *ifp = stdin;
    int raffle_person;
    int raffle_ticket;
    float raffle_price = 2.00;
    int avail_tickets = MAX_TICKETS;
    float profit = 0.0;

    while (avail_tickets > 0 &&
           fscanf(ifp, "%d", &raffle_ticket) == 1 && 
           fscanf(ifp, "%d", &raffle_person) == 1)
    {
        profit +=  Raffle(raffle_person, raffle_ticket, 
                          raffle_price, avail_tickets);
        avail_tickets = avail_tickets - raffle_ticket;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < raffle_index; i++)
        printf("Ticket %d for person %d\n", i, myRaffle.raffle_ticket[i]);

    printf("Profit = %.2f\n", profit);
    return 0;
}

float Raffle(int person, int req_tickets,
             float ticket_price, int avail_tickets)
{
    int i;
    float profit = 0;

    assert(avail_tickets > 0);
    if (avail_tickets < req_tickets)
        req_tickets = avail_tickets;
    printf("RAFFLE TICKETS %d - %d given to PERSON %d\n",
           raffle_index, raffle_index + req_tickets - 1, person);

    for (i = 0; i < req_tickets; i++)
    {
        myRaffle.raffle_ticket[raffle_index++] = person;
        profit+= ticket_price;
    }

    return profit;
}
```

Another day, we'll discuss the wisdom of repeatedly adding a floating
point number to another floating point number; it is not the way it
should be done, but will be adequate for the code at hand.

Comment: thanks, i am in intro to c hahah. But it is apart of a much larger program. it is so hard! oh well, ill have to take a C on this assignment. I got A's on all the others. ill have to study hard for a test in two week :P